# Unable to write Beautifulsoup4 output to csv with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I've been having problems with writing Python Beautifulsoup output into Pandas CSV file. As a final ouput I'd like `hreff` and `year2` on a separate columns each with multiple rows. But problem is both `link` and `year` give me a new list for every new line, so I get something like this when I print out one of them, for example `year2`:

```
['2001']
['2002'] etc...
```

but I want it like this:

```
['2001', '2002'] So that I could use it properly in a dataframe. (I Guess)
```

The code itself looks like this:

```
 for link in supp.find_all('div', {'class': 'poster'}):
        href = link.next.next
        hreff = href.get('href').splitlines()
        #print(hreff)
    for year in supp.find_all('div', {'class': 'data'}):
        try:
            year2 = year.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.text.splitlines()
        except AttributeError:
            continue

        columnlist = ['year']
        df = pd.DataFrame(year2, columns=columnlist)
        print(df)
        df.to_csv('xd.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

And when I print out the dataframe with year2, i get this output:

```
   year
0  2017
   year
0  2010
   year
0  2016
```

So, I'd like to know how do you correctly write two bs4 ouput lists into a CSV with pandas? Thanks and sorry for messy code and bad language. If something remains unclear I'll try to fix it fast.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the html you are using and what exactly it is you want to extract? At a guess the problem is you are creating a new dataframe within your for loop - you should add all your years to a list and then after the for loop create a dataframe from that list.

Comment: Accidentally added this as a answer but I'll copy-paste as comment: I get all the data I need from HTML without a problem, but passing them on to dataframe causes issues. At the moment I'm on the phone and can't provide you the HTML code but I'll try later if you still need it

Comment: Okay, i solved it. First I create list = [] outside the loop and then I append the lists inside the for loop and seems like it works now! Thanks since I could've not done it without your assistance!

Comment: happy to help - I have added my comment as an answer if you could accept it since it was what you needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess the problem is you are creating a new dataframe within your for loop - you should add all your years to a list and then after the for loop create a dataframe from that list.